# Code continues executing after validation error

Tags: c#, validation, data-binding, datatable, dataset

I have a c# winforms datagridview bound to a datatable within a dataset. I'm doing some testing purposely changing data in a column to be longer than the max length allows. I'm clicking the send button while my cursor is still within the cell I've just edited to make it too long. The application is giving me a validation error as expected but then the code inside the below if block is running anyways. My code and error message are below, what is a better way to do this and ensure that the code within the if block doesn't run if there are validation problems (any problems, not just max length issues)?

```
private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Validate())
    {
        bindingsource.EndEdit();
        //do more stuff, save data, etc...
    }
}
```

[image: error message]

Comment: Wrap the code inside `Validate()` inside of a `try/catch` block and return false on errors/handle the error gracefully.

Comment: the validate method is a native .net method, not one I wrote.

Comment: it seems that I have a misunderstanding of what the validate method does, it's obviously returning true when it seems like it should return a false. I think something related to that misunderstanding is where I'm going wrong.